# ReactJS Context API not passing the data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to use Context API to create a Trello Clone application. Currently the `ElementContext.js` does not pass any data to `App.js` or `HomePage.jsx`.

I have tried multiple different methods but all result in not finding the data or saying "... is not defined" or just simply not working. My code is listed below.

**App.js:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Todobox from './components/Todobox';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage'
import { ElementContext } from './ElementContext';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <ElementContext.Provider>
      <HomePage />
    </ElementContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ElementContext.js:**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import Todobox from './components/Todobox';

export const ElementContext = createContext();

export const ElementContextProvider = () => {
    const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

    const newElement = () =>{
        setElements('Todobox');
    };

    const value = {
        elements,
        setElements,
        newElement
    };

    return(
        <ElementContext.Provider value={value}> </ElementContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ElementContext;
```

**HomePage.jsx:**

```
import react from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import ElementContext from '../ElementContext';

export default function HomePage(){
    const newElement = useContext(ElementContext);
    return(
        <div className='page-container'>
        <div className='header'>
          <a className='header-title'>Trello Clone!</a>
          <a className='header-button' onClick={newElement}>Create a list</a>
        </div>
      <div className='element-field'>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

**Any help is appreciated since I am new! Thank you in advanced! :)**

Comment: In order to access the context the context.provider must be an ancestor of the component you're using it in. See the docs for some solid examples [React: useContext](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Todobox from './components/Todobox';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage'
import { ElementContextProvider } from './ElementContext';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <ElementContextProvider>   // NOT <ElementContext.Provider>
      <HomePage />
    </ElementContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ElementContext.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import Todobox from './components/Todobox';

export const ElementContext = createContext();

export const ElementContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

    const newElement = () =>{
        setElements('Todobox');
    };

    const value = {
        elements,
        setElements,
        newElement
    };

    return(
        <ElementContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}        // PASS CHILDREN COMPONENT
        </ElementContext.Provider>
    )
}

// export default ElementContext;  // REMOVE THIS LINE
```

Edited `HomePage.jsx`

```
import react from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import ElementContext from '../ElementContext';

export default function HomePage(){
    const { newElement } = useContext(ElementContext);  // NOT const newElement = useContext(ElementContext);
    return(
        <div className='page-container'>
        <div className='header'>
          <a className='header-title'>Trello Clone!</a>
          <a className='header-button' onClick={newElement}>Create a list</a>
        </div>
      <div className='element-field'>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: I made those adjustments, now I receive this error: "ERROR in ./src/components/HomePage.jsx 12:32-46

export 'default' (imported as 'ElementContext') was not found in '../ElementContext' (possible exports: ElementContext, ElementContextProvider)"

Any help? @Bikas

Comment: @Blazing. `import ElementContext from '../ElementContext';` => `import { ElementContext } from '../ElementContext';` in `Home.Pagejsx`. Because `ELementContext` is not exported as default.

Comment: @Blazing, I edited my answer. Please note that you export `elements`, `setElements`, `newElement` in one object as a `value` of `context`.

Comment: That worked thank you!! Now I am trying to update the state with "        setElements(...elements, Todobox);" but i receive the error: "TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"

Comment: @Blazing, What are you going to do exactly? Just adding `Todobox` to the existing state?
In that case, `setElement((prev) => [...prev, "Todobox"])`

Comment: thank you! I've been stuck on this for a bit. I am trying to make a [Trello](https://trello.com/) clone and trying to make the data easier to store then props.

Comment: I got it so that when I click "Create a list" it maps it and appears a <Todobox />. But how do I make it so that each <Todobox /> stores a special ID?

Comment: @Blazing. Could you create the project on `Sandbox` so I can modify there?

Comment: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-swanson-h14gyf?file=/package.json) . I am basically trying to make it to that every time you click "Create a list", each list has a unique ID assigned to it so that I can modify only that list.

Comment: @Blazing, I have modified your codes. Please check it. Hope it is just what you want to do at the moment and could be helpful for you. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-aryabhata-wzsqe1)